# jQuery draggable and -webkit-transform: scale();

Tags: jquery, draggable, webkit-transform

I have a situation where inside a `div` there are draggable items. However, when the parent `div` is scaled using `-webkit-transform`, the draggable obviously stops working properly.

I've reproduced the scenario [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vMaXm/).

As you can see, the draggable item moves relative to the document, even though the parent is in an entirely different scale.

I have the scale (`1.5` in the example) as a variable in JS, so I can use that, but where? I'd need to divide the dragging distance by the scale, right? Where could I do this?

**Edit:** I've tried setting a function to `drag`-event, but haven't been able to figure out how to actually alter the dragging distance.

**Edit2:** I digged the jQuery UI source, and it seems that there's no way to do this from the event `drag`:

```
if(this._trigger('drag', event, ui) === false) {
    this._mouseUp({});
    return false;
}
```

As you can see, the return value of the callback-function isn't stored in any way. The position of the element is changed *after* the callback has fired, so changing the CSS inside the callback doesn't work.

You can see the relevant code [here](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js) by using in-browser search with this string:

```
_mouseDrag: function(event, noPropagation) {
```

Comment: Aren't you missing 'containment' in the options of your example? Like this: $('.draggable').draggable({ containment: "parent" });​ Only then I can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Are you sure you're not seeing the issue without that? The issue is that the dragged element moves in a different scale, thus faster or slower than cursor.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Due to my small amount of experience with JavaScript I didn't realise that the callback could in fact modify the position, even though it doesn't `return` anything. This is because in JS apparently parameters are by default passed by reference.

Here's a working code:

```
// Couldn't figure out a way to use the coordinates
// that jQuery also stores, so let's record our own.
var click = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};

$('.draggable').draggable({

    start: function(event) {
        click.x = event.clientX;
        click.y = event.clientY;
    },

    drag: function(event, ui) {

        // This is the parameter for scale()
        var zoom = 1.5;

        var original = ui.originalPosition;

        // jQuery will simply use the same object we alter here
        ui.position = {
            left: (event.clientX - click.x + original.left) / zoom,
            top:  (event.clientY - click.y + original.top ) / zoom
        };

    }

});
```

Comment: All complex types (arrays, objects) are passed by reference in javascript. This has nothing to do with parameters :)

Comment: Though this solves the purpose bug containment "parent" for the draggable doesn't work after applying this code. Do you know how to overcome that?

Comment: @PrateekJain - I adapted Martti's answer to account for the containment (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40196570/1009922).

Comment: @Martti Laine - I'd recommend storing the zoom (aka. scale) in the start callback. I use this method with the resizeable widget, albeit with ui.size and ui.originalSize.

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is so late, this issue is posted 8 years ago but I did face it just yesterday, and I couldn't find any solution online.

Here's my solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/laith7ussein/normalize_ui_position)

```
var element_inside_the_scaled_container = $('#element');

$(element_inside_the_scaled_container).draggable({

    drag: function (event, ui) {

        var constants = normalize_ui_position('#elem_container', UI);

        console.log(constants); // They could be useful!

    }

});
```

The function I've called is available on my [github](https://github.com/laith7ussein/normalize_ui_position)

Answer (score -1):

I think you need the Transformable (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/transformable) jQuery plugin, in order to 'normalize' the WebKit scaling. Then dragging will work as in Firefox.

Here is the plugin - http://flin.org/js/jquery.transformable.js. I think it should resolve your problem. Here is my version of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/vMaXm/4/

```
$("#parent").setTransform("scalex", 1.5);
//$("#parent").setTransform("scaley", 1.5);
$('.draggable').draggable({ containment: "parent" });
```

​

However, at this moment, if I uncomment the middle line I get the same problem you report.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see the desired effect. Seems like `setTransform` simply resizes the parent back to normal size, though being in a different position.