# Jquery draggable with panzoom

Tags: jquery, jquery.panzoom

I am working on a page in witch all its contents are scaled by using panzoom. The problem is that when I drag something in the page the dragging item gets a bad position.

Comment: can you posy your relevant portion of JS/HTML?

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: Have you solved this issue?  No.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but perhaps I found answer.

Here two point:

- Don't move background while dragging object
- Scale cursor movement according to background scale

---

Below my code for zoomed background and move object over it.
Scale cursor based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13891338/6121703)

html

```
<script src = "/js/vendors/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src = "/js/vendors/jquery.panzoom.min.js"></script>

<div id = "map-viewport">
    <div id = "map">
        <div class = "draggable">1</div>
        <div class = "draggable">2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
var map = $('#map');
var viewport = $('#map-viewport');

map.panzoom({
    increment: 0.1,
    minScale: 1,
    contain: 'invert'
});

viewport.on('wheel', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var delta = e.delta || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
    var zoomOut = delta ? delta < 0 : e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0;
    map.panzoom('zoom', zoomOut, {
        increment: 0.2,
        animate: false,
        focal: e.originalEvent
    });
});

var click = { x: 0, y: 0};

$('.draggable')
    .draggable({
        containment: 'parent',
        start: function(e) {
            click.x = e.clientX;
            click.y = e.clientY;
        },

        drag: function(e, ui) {
            var m = map.panzoom('getMatrix');
            var zoom = Math.sqrt(m[0] * m[3]); // zoom don't change proportion and scale 
            var original = ui.originalPosition;

            ui.position = {
                left: (e.clientX - click.x + original.left) / zoom,
                top:  (e.clientY - click.y + original.top ) / zoom
            };
        }
    })
    .on('mousedown', function(e){ 
        e.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: You can find complete example [here](http://sgeproject.narod.ru/node/panzoom.zip). I add some Chrome stupid fix. In Chrome `mousemove` triggered for map instead map object. I suspect that it's collision between `z-index` and `transform` properties.

Comment: @AikonMogwai When I run this, and zoom in on the map then move the draggable it's position is off. My cursor is in one spot and the circle is up and left from it. Also, when my mouse is over a blue and I'm zoomed in on the map more of the map is shown. Any ideas what's going on there?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are. I'm using browser js. Draggable of jquery UI and Panzoom

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/Shturmavik/pen/zYqxaaP)

```
var viewport = $('.frame');
var $pz = $('.panzoom');
$pz.panzoom({
  minScale: .8,
  maxScale: 3,
  onPan: function() {
    //  console.log('pan');
  },
  onStart: function(event) {
    //  console.log('start', event);
    return true;
  },
});

$('.item').draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  appendTo: '.workspace',
  zIndex: 100505,
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    event.target.remove();
  },
});
```