# Using jquery panzoom alongside jquery draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery.panzoom

So I have this jquery `.draggable` items that work inside the `.droppable` and the `.droppable` parent uses the jquery `.panzoom`.
There is also a image for background witch is inside `.canvasimg`.

Here is a tree of my html structure:

```
<div class="wrapper"> //panzoom
    <div class="canvasimg">
        <img src="somebackground">
    </div>
    <div class="droppable">

        <div class="draggable">
        </div>
        <div class="draggable">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

What I have:

I have the zoom working and `draggable` working too. The problem is when I zoom in, the dragged item should be under the mouse but it kind of gets the "true" position, or the original position as you prefer..

If I start my drag from the top left of my `.droppable` with zoom in, it starts okay, the element is under the mouse, like this:
[image: starting drag from top left]

But as I go across the screen the element starts to "get away" from the mouse, the more I go right and bottom, more the element gets away from the mouse, like this:
[image: element getting off the mouse area]

What I'v tried:

To implement the answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33840054/jquery-draggable-with-panzoom) question but since I'm saving the position via ajax, I'm not very sure how can I use it, if the answer to this question is in this code:

```
var m = map.panzoom('getMatrix');
var zoom = Math.sqrt(m[0] * m[3]); // zoom don't change   proportion and scale 
var original = ui.originalPosition;

ui.position = {
    left: (e.clientX - click.x + original.left) / zoom,
    top:  (e.clientY - click.y + original.top ) / zoom
};
```

I'v tried using it, but no success.

what I thought:

Can I invert the matrix of the panzoom and use the css transform property in the draggable item with the oposite matrix?

**EDIT:**
So.. I successfully implemented this code:

```
 ui.position.top = Math.round(ui.position.top / zoom);
 ui.position.left = Math.round(ui.position.left / zoom);
```

In my function that gets the position of the element now the area that I have to drag the items reduces as I zoom in..

Probably I have to use a similar code in the `.droppable` div. to scale the .droppable as it scales the .wrapper?

**EDIT 2:** 
Created a question about the item [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581738/how-do-i-get-the-zoomed-size-of-a-element-with-jquery-panzoom-and-jquery-droppab).

Comment: I notice that you haven't accepted any answers to your other questions. You may like to consider doing that when an answer helps. It will increase your reputation, and reward those that help you.  You can accept an answer by clicking the tick mark next to it

Comment: oh thank you k Scandrett. I should have done it

Comment: Did you answer your question? If not, I was going to suggest maybe wrapping the zoomed element and make the wrapper draggable.

Comment: The `.wrapper` pans with panzoomer,  I did answered the question but still having trouble, I think its the area that `.draggable`  is not using the current size of the `.droppable`, i think it is using the size at the start, and when it zooms the drop area keeps the same in the `.draggable` but `.droppable` changes size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have succesfully solved this problem using:

```
        var realheight = $(".droppable").eq(0).height() * zoom;
        var realwidth = $(".droppable").eq(0).width() * zoom ; 

        ui.position.top =  ui.position.top / zoom ;
        ui.position.left = ui.position.left / zoom;     
        ui.position.left - (ui.helper.outerWidth()/2)

        xpos = (((parseFloat(ui.helper.css("left"))   /  realwidth) * 100) * zoom) * zoom ; 
        ypos = (((parseFloat(ui.helper.css("top"))   / realheight) * 100) * zoom) * zoom  ; 

        ui.helper.css({top : ypos+"%", left: xpos+"%"});
```