# jQueryUi Draggable inside scaled iframe not working properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on an application, where a main page loads another page inside iframe. The page inside iframe `<html>` tag has css3 scaling applied

```
html{
        -webkit-transform:scale(.5);
    }
```

Now jqueryui draggable inside the iframe,has some weird behavior. When I drag an element inside the iframe page, the draggable element doesn't catch up with mouse, i.e mouse move farther/faster than the element.

Is there any way to correct this behaviour

Everything is working locally , no server involved. This is basically Readium Epub viewer, JavaScript application.
[image]

Comment: You can take a look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14890648/1009922.

Comment: There is one script that work well without jquery-ui draggable, but it is not compatible with jquery-ui droppable.

Comment: Maybe this one works better for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13891338/1009922.