# how to make jquery-ui droppable accept element other that jquery-ui draggable

Tags: jquery-ui

I have made a draggable element that doesnt use jqueryui-draggable.

I want to use it alongside jquery ui droppable. Is it possible for jquery-ui droppable to accept any draggable that are not made by jquery-ui? and how?

Please see plnkr
https://plnkr.co/edit/BzNuFtSUGaXmVhpNpqLG?p=preview

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
 // $("#drag2").draggable();

  $("#drag").drags();

  $(".droppable").droppable({
    drop:function(event,ui){
      $(this).append('dropped')
    },
    accept: ".draggable1"
  })
})
```

Comment: You may want to edit your post. If your question is, is it possible, the answer would be "Yes".

Comment: @Twisty, Can you please guide me how to do that!

Comment: Would need more info, some type of example of what you're doing currently. Please update your post with an example of what you have tried.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `draggable()`?

Comment: Been plugging away at this all day. I think I have a solution that involves triggering `drop` event on the target. My test area: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/j7Lzsfcx/ The drop is still not accepting the custom element and I suspect there is something else that is being triggered in `dragstart` that I have to hook into.

Comment: I am currently working on EPUB, it is being read in READIUM viewer, where page is scaled using css3 transform, thus .draggable not work as expected. but .droppable works. Plase see my another quesiotn to explain this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181735/jqueryui-draggable-inside-scaled-iframe-not-working-properly