# jQuery draggable with scaled element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Hello I have problem with my cursor in jQuery draggable on scaled element.
My code looks like :

```
$(".jdragable").draggable({
  revert: false,
  scroll: false,
  appendTo: '.page',
  helper: 'clone',
  zIndex: 3000,
  start: function(event, ui) {
    // hide parent element
    $(event.target).hide();

    // apply scale on cloned element
    $(ui.helper).css({
      transform: 'scale(' + getScale() + ')'
    });
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    $(event.target).show();
  },
  drag: function(event, ui) {}
});
```

When I start drag if scale is 1 everything works pretty, but when scale is lower, let's say 0,5 cursor has strange position (displacement).

What should I do to have cursor on same position on element as dragged start ?

Please help.

Comment: Similar but not exact duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882070/jquery-draggable-and-webkit-transform-scale

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Drag/Resize with CSS Transform Scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212683/jquery-drag-resize-with-css-transform-scale)

Comment: If you can add fiddle we can help you better.